# myhdl cosimulation test fail

Tags: iverilog, myhdl

I am trying to download myhld on ubuntu and also install the cosimulation. myhdl was installed fine but when following the cosimulation installation i am unable to properly run the test case provided within the download package. an error is coming when running the made test.

I have installed myhld using pip3 install myhdl 
for co simulation I have gone into my cosimulation directory in

~/.local/share/myhdl/cosimulation/icarus/

hit make just like the makefile told me. a myhdl.vpi was created.
I copied that myhdl.vpi file into the test directory

~/.local/share/myhdl/cosimulation/icarus/test

here I ran the test_all.py using the cmd python3 test_all.py

http://www.myhdl.org/start/installation.html

pip3 install myhdl

after installing move to directory for cosimulator outpout
cd ~/.local/share/myhdl/cosimulation/icarus

make 
cp myhdl.vpi test/

python3 test_all.py

I expected the test to pass but it failed to produce an error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_gray.py", line 27, in 
    import test_gray_properties, test_gray_original
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_gray_properties'

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. The pip install only installs the cosimulation directory under the shares, but the test_gray.py appends the path "../../../example/manual". This is where the test_gray_properties.py would be, but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by downloading the files from a github directory and compiling in the current work folder, as you can see here:

https://github.com/bat52/cryptech/blob/master/pycryptech/pueda/icarus.py